# No error in browser but output is not getting displayed in browser. Using webpack server, nodejs, npm

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, command-prompt, webpack-dev-server

This is for Hello World basic build. The bundle.js file is getting generated so the 404 server not found error was resolved. The following is the code. There is no error message when the localhost is started. The browser is blank. The Hello World is not getting displayed.

```
The below file is index.html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src= "bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The below file is app.js

```
document.write('Hello World');
console.log('app loaded Hello World');
```

Below is the webpack-config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./app.js", 
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
      }
}
```

I have installed webpack, nodejs, npm, babel etc

At the command prompt the command that was executed was webpack-dev-server
The image is of localhost in F12 mode or Debugging mode. See, no errors[image: localhost in F12 OR DEBUGGING MODE]
The second image is of the command prompt[image: command prompt]

Comment: Initially, I entered the following at the command prompt                 :         webpack ./app.js bundle.js

Comment: I did some troubleshooting and it was a simple error. The config file should be renamed webpack.config.js   The error was that my file was named webpack-config.js (Note the dash - which should be replaced with dot). Problem resolved. Question closed